# How to create an object of interface value type in go using reflection

Tags: go, reflection

**UPDATED**

I want to make helper function for testing reading env vars function. It uses [envconfig](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig).

```golang
func Test_T2(t *testing.T) {

    os.Setenv("APP_PARAM_STR", "string value")
    os.Setenv("APP_PARAM_INT", "12")

    os.Setenv("APP_PARAM_DURATION", "15s")
    os.Setenv("APP_PARAM_INT", "44")

    c := ConfigTwo{}

    d := ConfigTwo{
        ParamDuration: 15*time.Second,
        ParamInt:      44,
    }

    helper(t, &c, &d)
}

func helper(t *testing.T, confObject, expValue interface{}) {
    t.Helper()

    err := getParams(&confObject)
    if !assert.NoError(t, err) {
        return
    }

    assert.Equal(t, expValue, confObject)
}

func getParams(cfg interface{}) error {
    return envconfig.Process("APP", cfg)

}

** UPDATE 2 **
It works. Thanks everyone.
```

It works if I have getPrams function only. But if I add helper (that I need to test different structs) I get an error:
`specification must be a struct pointer`

**envconfig** performs two checks [here](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig/blob/c974cae29cf5b543b30f7ba91f8ce9649cd69818/envconfig.go#L64):

Comment: The check checks if `s` is a pointer to a struct, so whatever your `helperFunc` does, if it doesn't return a pointer to a struct then you will not be able to make it work. And what is you question btw? Are you asking how to create a pointer to a struct with reflection? Or are you asking how to copy arbitrary values with reflection? Two.very.differrent.things.

Comment: yes, how to create a pointer, that's my question

Comment: [`reflect.New`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New) returns a pointer to the given type. It's just like the builtin function `new`, when you do `new(string)` in Go you get a value of type `*string`, i.e. a pointer to the given type. https://play.golang.org/p/cmtvfJrLG1r

Comment: reflect.New returns reflect.Value. 
```
 paramType := reflect.PtrTo(reflect.TypeOf(param))
 cpy := reflect.New(paramType).Interface()

 err := envconfig.Process(defaultAppPrefix, cpy)
``` 
this causes an error ```specification must be a struct pointer``` because ```reflect.ValueOf(cpy).Elem().Kind()``` is Ptr instead of Struct.

Comment: Edit the question to show how `helperFunc` is called (including the argument type) and the expected return type and value. It may be that the reflect.PtrTo call is unnecessary, but we cannot tell without seeing how the function is used.

Comment: I did na update. Please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code.  The argument is a pointer to the expected value.

```
func helper(t *testing.T, pexpected interface{}) {
    t.Helper()
    pactual := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(pexpected).Elem()).Interface()

    err := getParams(pactual)
    if !assert.NoError(t, err) {
        return
    }

    assert.Equal(t, pexpected, pactual)
}
```

The expression `reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(pexeceted).Elem()).Interface()` returns a pointer to a new empty value with the same type as what pexpected points to.

Call it like this:

```
helper(t, &ConfigTwo{A: "expected A Field", B: "expected B field"}
```